# Is it possible to make getElementById part of a function?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to set player1's choice to an option from an array but I have no idea if I'm even close to the right track. Can I put document.getElementById into a function the way I have here?

edit: added the full HTML and JS code so you can see what I'm working on.

```js
let cpu = {
  currentChoice: null,
};
let player1 = {
  currentChoice: null,
};

const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"]; //makes the variable array 'choices'

function computerChooses() {
  const cpuMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // returns a random integer from 0 to 2, which will become the computer's move in the next line of code

  cpu.currentChoice = choices[cpuMove]; //makes the integer from computerChooses the computer's move 
}

function playerChooses() {
  if (document.getElementById('0').onClick) {
    player1.currentChoice = choices[0];
  } else if (document.getElementById('1').onClick) {
    player1.currentChoice = choices[1];
  } else if (document.getElementById('2').onClick) {
    player1.currentChoice = choices[2];
  }
}

playerChooses();

function compareChoices() {

  computerChooses(); //call the computer choice function inside the compare choices function
  if (cpu.currentChoice === player1.currentChoice) { //if there's a tie
    displayWinner("Tie! CPU and Player1 both chose " + cpu.currentChoice);
  } else if (cpu.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
    if (player1.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
      displayWinner("Player1 wins! CPU chose " + cpu.currentChoice + " and Player1 chose " + player1.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayWinner("CPU chose " + cpu.currentChoice + " and Player1 chose " + player1.currentChoice);
    }

  } else if (cpu.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
    if (player1.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
      displayWinner("Player1 wins! CPU chose " + cpu.currentChoice + " and Player1 chose " + player1.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayWinner("CPU wins! CPU chose " + cpu.currentChoice + " and Player1 chose " + player1.currentChoice);
    }
  } else if (cpu.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
    if (player1.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
      displayWinner("Player1 wins! CPU chose " + cpu.currentChoice + " and Player 1 chose " + player1.currentChoice);
    } else {
      displayWinner("CPU wins! CPU chose " + cpu.currentChoice + " and Player1 chose " + player1.currentChoice);
    }
  }
}
compareChoices();

function displayWinner(result) {
  const whoWon = document.createElement('p');
  whoWon.innerText = result;
  document.body.appendChild(whoWon);
}
```

```html
<h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors for Romans!</h1>
<h2>Let's get into it: Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus</h2>
<p>Look, it's the same, we just changed it to Latin words. There you go. You know how to play Rock, Paper, Scissors.<br> <br>Make your move: </p>
<button id="0">Lapis</button>
<button id="1">Papyrus</button>
<button id="2">Scalpellus</button>
```

}
}

Comment: The elements with IDs `0`, `1`, `2`, what are they? Checkboxes? Or radio elements?

Comment: Show more context, please. How does the HTML looks? Where are you calling playerChooses?

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with `getElementById` itself, but rather whatever you are expecting `if (document.getElementById('0').onClick)` to mean.  To answer *the question asked*, yes, you most certainly can use `getElementById` in a function.  I can't imagine any reason why that would ever be forbidden.  But to solve *the problem faced* may require more context about whatever it is you're trying to build.

Comment: This needs some more context (is player1 a class or an object, is this vanillaJS or are you using a framework...) but for starters, you want to add an event listener to those DOM elements.

Comment: Are you just asking [how to handle a click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)?  It seems like the scope of the code shown far exceeds the actual problem.  If you don't know how to handle a click on a button, focus on *just that* first before building a larger application around that concept.

Answer (score -1):

element's id don't start with a number

```js
let d1s = document.getElementsByClassName("d1")

var player = {}

for(let i=0;i<d1s.length;i++){
  d1s[i].onclick = function(){
    player.select = d1s[i].innerText
    d2.innerText = player.select
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="d1">a</div> <div class="d1">b</div> <div class="d1">c</div>
</div>

<div id="d2"></div>
```

Comment: I don't agree on answering a question that lacks context, like why are we even seeing if onClick property exists.

besides this doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: @niceman And the statement is also only true for HTML4.x (and below). HTML5 allows numeric ids.

Answer (score -1):

give all the buttons a class so you can select them if you end up having other buttons and add a data attribute

```
    <button class="btn-choice" data-choice="Paper">Lapis</button>
    <button class="btn-choice" data-choice="Rock">Papyrus</button>
    <button class="btn-choice" data-choice="Scissors">Scalpellus</button>
```

then select all buttons and add an event listener and set the player choice to that data attribute.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-choice');
let playerChoice = '';

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerChoice = button.dataset.choice;
    console.log(playerChoice);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To make things easier let's add a class to these buttons:

```
<button name="rock" class="choice-btn" id="1">Rock</button>
<button name="paper" class="choice-btn" id="2">Paper</button>
<button name="scissors" class="choice-btn" id="3">Scissors</button>
```

Then in JS we can do the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".choice-btn").forEach((node) => {
    node.onclick = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.name);
    };
});
```

Instead of console logging you can do what you need to do with the result.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!